# how to draw a popover view instead of using image on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uiview, popover

just like the popover in the attached screenshots, the popover allow user to change themes. 
I know that there are some examples around but they are all using images to achieve this, make it hard to change themes.

I believe the app in the screenshots doesn't using images to do it.

thanks for any help!

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

In my Win background such skins (called "Flat" in Delphi and WinForms) were made by drawing in code: select a color, draw a line, select another color, draw a rounded rectangle and so on.

Also, it is necessary to introduce a class "ColorTheme" with a set of fields for every color used. You may have several ColorTheme instances and swap them when you need to change color theme.